# Neo4j and Rest API with Cloud (Heroku)

Tags: neo4j

Because there is no documentation online how to use Neo4j and Rest API with Cloud (Heroku)
at the https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-java-rest-binding library , there are no example how to use this API

A picture that show the situation :
https://docs.google.com/document/d/14VqI1MNia_m5TJgWF4ky3H71kfP-LmCe16Fp0oKSyJo/pub

I would an example to execute a Query or use Rest API , I use java 
example how to Create a node how to iterate an Query Result

Thank you in advance.

Comment: See [Neo4j's documentation on the rest API](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api.html).

Comment: here at the documentation How to use the REST API from Java
http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/tutorials-rest.html
they use  Jersey as a local server 

so it doesn't work  for heroku

Comment: Are you asking about how to set up Neo4j on Heroku? Did you trying googling for "neo4j heroku"? This is the first link that comes up: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/neo4j

Comment: No , i have setup neo4j on Heroku, 
Because there is no examples related to neo4j and Heroku, I would like an example that show how to use RestAPI with JSON with neo4j and Heroku
how to Create a node how to iterate an Query Result